# Elasticsearch: record history of changing index

Tags: elasticsearch

We're using elasticsearch to store data related to the features that our customers use. The index, say `feature-usage` is updated every time a customer activates or deactivates a feature.

Sample data:

```
Customer ID, Uses feature A, Uses feature B
1          , true          , false
2          , true          , true
3          , false         , true
4          , true          , false
```

This data reflects the "right now". There's no timestamp attached.

One of the views I can currently provide based on that is:

- feature A is used by 3 customers right now.
- feature B is used by 2 customers right now.

I would like to be able to show a history for this data:

- feature A was used by 2 customers yesterday
- feature A was used by 1 customer 2 days ago

Essentially, I want to create a graph showing the evolution of feature usages. For that, I need to store historical data, which I imagine would look something like this:

```
Day       , customers using feature A, customers using feature B
2021-05-17, 2                        , 1
2021-05-18, 3                        , 1
2021-05-19, 2                        , 2
```

On a SQL database, I would probably run a nightly cron job to generate this data. I tried playing around with elasticsearch's transforms and rollups, but I couldn't figure out a good solution.

Is there a way to transform `feature-usage` into the historical data as shown here, using only elasticsearch and no external code/cron jobs?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your index with an ingestion pipeline that adds the current timestamp, when the data is ingested. So you would have historical information.

You can define a sample pipeline as reported [in the official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html#access-ingest-metadata)

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/my-pipeline
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "description": "Index the ingest timestamp as 'event.ingested'",
        "field": "event.ingested",
        "value": "{{{_ingest.timestamp}}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, you can set the default pipeline for your index:

```
PUT feature-usage
{
  "index.default_pipeline": "my-pipeline"
}
```

Now you should have a timestamp (`event.ingested`) for each document. Now you should be able to work with date_histograms and find the answers you seek.

The idea is that first you aggregate the data based on the date and then perform counts based on conditions.

Kind regards,
Mirko

Comment: I don't think this is going to work for my use case: data in `feature-usage` is not time-based. See it as a settings table you would have in a typical SQL database. It's updated every time the customer activates or deactivates a feature, but there is no history included.

Comment: Perhaps, I did not get your question right. However, I don't get how you can show historical information without storing it (don't you agree?). As shown in my answer, you can transform your data in "historical" one, by adding a timestamp during ingestion time. For instance for a given user-id, I have a document (with timestamp) for each update of the features. 
In order to show the current feature, I can retrieve the last indicized document for the customer with a Top Hit aggregation. Hope it helps

Comment: Oh, I see the misunderstanding: I cannot modify `feature-usage` data itself, as many things already depend on it and would break. Though I could duplicate it and attach timestamps.

But even with a timestamp attached to every change, not all companies are refreshed at the same time, so I'd have to somehow do a rolling sum... That doesn't sound like the easy solution I'm looking for :)